# using bitshift in c++ to set two bits to 0 resp 1

Tags: c++, binary, logical-operators, bit-shift

Assuming x is a 8bit unsigned integer, what is the most efficient command to set the last two bits to `01` ?
So regardless of the initial value it should be `x = ******01` in the final state.

In order to set

- the last bit to 1, one can use OR like `x |= 00000001`, and
- the forelast bit to 0, one can use AND like `x &= 11111101` which is `~(1<<1)`.

Is there an arithmetic / logical operation that can be use to apply both operations at the same time?

Can this be answered independently of programm-specific implementation but pure logical operations?

Comment: _Is there an arithmetic / logical operation that can be use to apply both operations at the same time?_ No (sits back and waits for someone to tell me how to do it)

Comment: @PaulSanders This is how you do it :) ... Use a lookup table. There are only 256 values. `table[i]` is only one *logical* operation. However, I don't expect this to be faster than two bitwise operations, which I gather is the goal of the question.

Comment: @bitmask: by shifting the input, you can do with a 64-entries LUT. At the expense of even slower operation. :-)

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think we can do even better. If we set up a mysql server we can solve the problem in just a single query. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can put both operation in one instructions.

```
x = (x & 0b11111100) | 1;
```

That at least saves one assignment and one memory read/write. However, most likely the compilers may optimize this anyway, even if put into two instructions.

Depending on the target CPU, compilers may even optimize the code into bit manipulation instructions that directly can set or reset single bits. And if the variable is locally heavily used, then most likely its kept in register.

So at the end the generated code may look at as simple as (pseudo asm):

```
load x
setBit 0
clearBit 1
store x
```

however it also may be compiled into something like

```
load x to R1
load immediate 0b11111100 to R2
and  R1, R2
load immediate 1 to R2
or   R1, R2
store R1 to x
```

For playing with things like this you may throw a look at compiler explorer https://godbolt.org/z/sMhG3YTx9
Please try removing the `-O2` compiler option and see the difference between optimized and non-optimized code. Also you may try to switch to different cpu architectures and compilers

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with a dyadic bitwise operator. Because the second operand should allow to distinguish between "reset to 0", "set to 1" or "leave unchanged". This cannot be encoded in a single binary mask.

---

Instead, you can use the bitwise ternary operator and form the expression

`x = 0b11111100 ??? x : 0b00000001`.

Anyway, a piece of caution: this operator does not exist.

Comment: Could you clarify? Is that operator the same as "?" or what does this??? x will be casted to bool and assigned a value depending on its former value (?)

Comment: @pas-calc: read the whole post.